# each exception sends internal server error

Tags: java, spring, security, spring-security, jwt

I have written a jwt filter for doing database operations and controlling taken tokens but the OncePerRequestFilter that i extends send always http status 500 "internal server error" when throw an exception. How can i fix it?

```
    @Component
public class JwtTokenFilter extends OncePerRequestFilter {


    @Autowired
    private TokenManager tokenManager;

    private IgniteRepository repository;

    public JwtTokenFilter(IgniteRepository repository) {
        this.repository = repository;
    }

    @Override
    protected void doFilterInternal(HttpServletRequest httpServletRequest,
                                    @NotNull HttpServletResponse httpServletResponse,
                                    @NotNull FilterChain filterChain) throws ServletException, IOException {

        //System.out.println(tokenManager.generateToken("qq"));
        String authorizationHeader = httpServletRequest.getHeader(HttpHeaders.AUTHORIZATION);

        if (Strings.isNullOrEmpty(authorizationHeader) || !authorizationHeader.startsWith("Bearer")) {
            throw new JwtNullException();//this is my own exception class and it sends 401
        }

        String token = authorizationHeader.substring(7);
        String afId = tokenManager.getUsernameToken(token);
        repository.putCache(afId,new APIInvokerEnrolmentDetails());


        //System.out.println(afId+" "+token);
        if (!repository.containsAtCache(afId)){
           throw new OnboardedAFException(); //this is my own exception class and it sends 403
        }



        filterChain.doFilter(httpServletRequest, httpServletResponse);
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

The "500 internal" error is the message that occurs during an exception in the server. I think you should use a "try and catch" to generate these errors and select its return status.